# Is there any way to select and stage multiple files at once in GitKraken?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I want to stage multiple files at the same time by selecting them together and click "stage", something which is fairly easy to do in other Git clients such as SourceTree, Smartgit or Magit.

In GitKraken it seems that I can only click "stage file" once at a time instead of shift-selecting them all and stage them all at once.

I haven't been able to find an answer on the web even though it sounds like an easy enough functionality.

Comment: I do not think this is possible. You can stage all files, single files or parts of files, that's about it.

Answer (score 3):

No, its not possible right now. It's crazy

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a while ago but someone may find it useful.

Although you can't select multiple items, you do have the option to stage/ignore folders when viewing files in the treeview pane.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of [GitKraken](https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-files/staging), your can stage one file at a time or you can stage all files at once. There is no option to stage only few files while leaving other changes unstaged.